# Modular formula reference in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way in Google Sheets for a cell Y to reference another cell X so that X's formula is re-used in the context of Y? I want Y to act as if I copied and pasted X into it, but also to change if X changes.

More explicitly, say I have a cell X with this formula, and the value of A1 is 3, and A2 is 2:

`=SUM(A1:A2)`

(which would evaluate to 5)

Now suppose I have values 4 and 5 in B1 and B2, and I want to sum them. I could of course copy the formula in X and paste it into some cell Y with the same offset from B (resulting in `=SUM(B1:B2)`), but then if I changed the formula in X, I would have to re-paste it into Y if I also wanted Y to change. What I would like is for Y to contain:

`=GETFORMULAFROM(X)`

and have it evaluate to 9 as if it were that formula, copied and pasted. Then, if I were to later change X to `=PRODUCT(A1:A2)`, X would display 6 and Y would display 20. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Script solution

The following Apps Script function (to be entered in script editor, Tools > Script Editor) will update the "target" cells, so that they contain the same formulas as source cells, with references remapped appropriately.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sources = ['A3', 'C4', 'C5'];  // cells from which to copy 
  var targets = ['F3', 'E7', 'G1'];  // cells to which to copy, in the same order 
  var i = sources.indexOf(e.range.getA1Notation());
  if (i != -1) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    e.range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(targets[i]));
  }
}
```

This doesn't give precisely want the question wants, but if you don't mind manually updating the source and target ranges when appropriate and can handle the performance issues from running an Apps script in your onEdit event, this is a reasonable approximation without getting too complicated.

Example: entering `=sum(B1:B3) + $C$1` in cell C4 will result in the corresponding target, E7, having `=sum(D4:D6) + $C$1`. That is, relative references and absolute references are treated the same way as they are when copy-pasting formulas.

#### Without a script

Spreadsheet formulas cannot access other formulas entered in the sheet.

But similar functionality is provided by [array formulas](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en), in the sense that by entering a formula once, one can apply it to an entire range. For example:

```
=arrayformula(A1:1 + A2:2)
```

returns the sum A1+A2, B1+B2, C1+C2, and so on. If this formula is changed to

```
=arrayformula(A1:1 * A2:2)
```

all these sums become products.

Comment: I looked into arrayformula, and it does partially do what I'm interested in, but it has an important restriction that a) it doesn't allow me to arbitrarily specify where X and Y are (they are presented as offsets of the cell containing the arrayformula calculation) and b) it requires me to adjust new input cells in the arrayformula range as I add them (rather than allowing me to copy a template into a new, arbitrary, location).

Comment: I added a script that achieves exactly the effect you want.

Comment: I was looking at the range API yesterday, and had no idea that copyTo would preserve copy/paste behavior, so that's great knowledge. It is still missing the key modularity functionality where the dependent target doesn't need to be known about by the source (the same way a function in an imperative language doesn't have to be defined with all the places it will be used), and putting an appsScript in an onEdit will probably have some performance issues, but I imagine this is as close as Google will let it get

Comment: I can probably make a change to this that will fulfill that modularity requirement, I'll fiddle with it in a little bit and show it

Comment: Any attempt I made to implement this ran into a fundamental problem, which is that the copy process will tend to remove backwards references, and that I would need to be in a cumbersome and error-prone position of maintaining a content registry in the onEdit event in order to have it work automatically in the way I would like (and somehow have that same event intelligently clobber itself or not if the cell is edited later). I'm going to chalk this up to the limitations of Google Sheets, put some caveats in your answer, and accept it